# Getting error: Could not load type "jms_choose_payment_method" with Symfony2 JMSPaymentCoreBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to install the master branch of the JMSPaymentCoreBundle yesterday and am trying to use some of the code from the documentation.

On executing

```
$this->getFormFactory()->create('jms_choose_payment_method'...
```

I'm getting the error:

Could not load type "jms_choose_payment_method"

I installed the bundle with deps file. I have done the registerBundle (in AppKernel.php) and registerNamespace (in autoload.php). I can see that the file vendor\bundles\JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Form\ChoosePaymentMethodType.php exists and that vendor\bundles\JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Resources\config\payment.xml does contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<parameters>
...
    <parameter key="payment.form.choose_payment_method_type.class">JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Form\ChoosePaymentMethodType</parameter>
...
</parameters>

<services>
...
    <service id="payment.form.choose_payment_method_type" class="%payment.form.choose_payment_method_type.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="payment.plugin_controller" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="jms_choose_payment_method" />
    </service>
</services>
</container>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or, is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This bundle currently works only with symfony 2.1